# Is it possible to display GKAchievementViewController and GKLeaderboardViewController together?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, gamekit, game-center

Is it possible to display both the Game Kit Leaderboard and Achievement controllers simultaneously?

Documentation for both of these controllers is very light.

[GKAchievementViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKAchievementViewController_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

[GKLeaderboardViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboardViewController_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are calling to different views.. you can only set leaderboard display first.. and when user closes leaderboard, it show achievements.. or vice-versa..

in your function:

```
-(void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{//when leaderboard closes..
//run achievements ViewController..
}
```

Comment: This is what I have now. Too bad I cannot consolidate views. Thanks.

Comment: @OhDannyBoy Will you please explain the Code to do this.. I am Not able to present achievementViewController After dismissing leader boardViewController. If I try to present individually they both r working fine.. I am writing [self showAchievements]; method after dismissing leaderBoardViewController. but it is not working.

Comment: I believe I added a delay to show the second controller after dismissing the first. [self performSelector:@selector(showaAhievementViewController ) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.05f];

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own view controller & implement leaderboards & achievements together - how it would work (for the user I mean) I've no idea, but the code wouldn't be that hard, it's well documented.